# Cached images are not loaded in HTTPs

Tags: image, cache, security

In my custom theme, I'm loading products images using this :

```
 <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(182) ?>" width="182" height="182" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>" />
```

Unfortunatly, theses images are the only medias that are not loaded in https while the website is accessed in https. I double checked configuration.

Example of the resulting url :

```
http://mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/182x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/n/o/non_deco_mix_plus_1_candle_best.jpg
```

Note : I've also tried to flush the cache, no clue.

Is there anything else I should do or verify about that?

Comment: Tried `Flush Catalog Images Cache`?

Comment: Yes, as noted in the question already.

Comment: upvote............from me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It **`admin>system>configuration>web>`** Secure tab and check `Base Media URL` contain  **https** `protocol`.

That mean **url should be start** with `https` for media

Comment: Yes it is working, but is it the only way?

Comment: yes,it only way.As your ssl pages base url  is https so need all image call with https. when call https it port protecting to call http

Comment: Well I mean the Secure tab was already in HTTPS but changing also the non secure to HTTPS fixed the issue... which should not be needed.